# significance of using aria-hidden=true in angular

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium-webdriver

```
<a _ngcontent-c6="" id="addEmployeeButton" routerlink="/employees/add" href="/employees/add">
                    <mat-icon _ngcontent-c6="" class="worksuite plus mat-icon material-icons" role="img" aria-hidden="true"></mat-icon>
                </a>
```

How do I locate the employee button for the above code using selenium webdriver by using Java. I am getting

> "Element not found exception"

Comment: <a _ngcontent-c6="" id="addEmployeeButton" routerlink="/employees/add" href="/employees/add">
     <mat-icon _ngcontent-c6="" class="worksuite plus mat-icon material-icons" role="img" aria-hidden="true"></mat-icon>
    </a>

Comment: How is the title related to the actual question? Also, please don't post code in comments, edit your question instead. _And_ add your code.

Comment: @aron You need to Share your trial code too,

Comment: please provide the code and actual error you are getting

Comment: you are getting issue in finding the selector or getting the element. what selector are you using to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

If an element is only visible after some user action, authors MUST set the aria-hidden attribute to true. When the element is presented, authors MUST set the aria-hidden attribute to false or remove the attribute, indicating that the element is visible. Some assistive technologies access WAI-ARIA information directly through the DOM and not through platform accessibility supported by the browser. Authors MUST set aria-hidden="true" on content that is not displayed, regardless of the mechanism used to hide it. This allows assistive technologies or user agents to properly skip hidden elements in the document.

For more details:

- https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden
- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/semantics-aria/hiding-and-updating-content?hl=en